# How to optimize the following three lines of code

Tags: php, performance, optimization

If have a function (in PHP although that's irrelevant in this case) that needs to return the value of a boolean variable (which could be either true or false at this point) and then set that same variable to false as its value has already been reported. The code looks like that:

```
$return_value = $report_boolean;
$report_boolean = false;
return $return_value;
```

Basically I want to return whatever is contained in the `$report_boolean` and then make sure it's set to `false` after that. Is there a way to do that in one line without using the extra 'keep track' variable?

Comment: why set `$report_boolean` to false if this is within a function as it's scope is only available in that function anyway (surely) ~ just return the `$report_boolean`?

Comment: $report_boolean is global variable so it could be changed outside the scope of the function. Every time that happens it is set to true (something like setting up a flag) until somebody checks it. Once they do, it should go back to false until it is set to true again. I don't think it's that complicated of a scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do the assignment on the `return` call, and make sure it runs (beware of lazy evaluation):

`return $return_value && (($return_value = false)||true)`

Comment: Nice trick, thank you!
Wouldn't '$return_value = false' always be true though as you can always perform that action? You wouldn't need the '||true' in that case.

Comment: `$return_value = false` always returns false. It's an assignment, and it returns the assigned value.
Another way would be `!($return_value = false)`

Comment: Yep, just found that out the hard way. Thank you very much though, your code works just as intended!

Comment: Are you sure that's any faster?  This has a branch (for short-circuit eval of `&&`).  I assume you mean `$report_boolean` instead of the `$return_value` tmp var, so this avoids creation of a tmp var.  I guess that's expensive in php?

Comment: You're right, there's no need for both in this case. that's what's nice about this solution.
Personally - I'd prefer the clearer and longer approach (even with the extra variable). Readability is the best choice IMO.
As for performance - I would assume that the original is faster :/